# Problems installing PEAR on IIS7.5 php 5.4.7

Tags: php, iis, installation, iis-7.5, pear

I have done a manual install of php 5.4.7 on IIS 7.5 (no msi installer as far as I know) and am now attempting to install PEAR. The instructions for installing it here http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php are pretty useless as the go-pear.bat doesn't exist in my install of php. So instead I've followed the instuctions [here](http://code.rawlinson.us/2012/02/install-php-pear-on-windows-7.html) but pretty much fall at the part which says to run php go-pear.phar from the command prompt. First I get a system error dialog saying "The program can't start because fbclient.dll is missing" which I dismiss, followed by "The program can't start because OCI.dll is missing" which I also dismiss, php then returns me to the command prompt.

I'm new to installing php and PEAR, in the past I've just used installers which generally worked fine. Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Edit your PHP.ini file, and comment out the following extensions:

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
```

Turns out none of those are actually included in the standard Windows PHP installation package, despite being left enabled in the PHP.ini files that are meant to be for Windows servers... opensource dumbasses.